# How to implement deep linking in Flutter with GoRouter while using GetX for In-App routing?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-go-router

I've been using GetX for routing in my Flutter app for quite some time and it's been working great. However, I now have a requirement to implement deep linking using GoRouter. I'm not sure how to integrate GoRouter for deep linking while still maintaining my existing GetX-based routing system.

Here are some of the specific challenges I'm facing:

- How can I set up **deep linking** routes with **GoRouter** in my Flutter app?
- Is it possible to use GoRouter for deep linking while preserving the benefits of GetX routing?
- Are there any best practices or examples that demonstrate the integration of GoRouter and GetX for deep linking in Flutter?

I'd appreciate any guidance or code samples that can help me achieve deep linking functionality in my Flutter app while continuing to use GetX for my existing routing needs.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Go through this package: **uni_links**

The below link can help you to gather more information.
https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-deep-linking-flutter-uni-links/

Note: The basic code level is the same for most of the state-management tools. Make sure you cover up the core functionality. Once it works properly, you can modify it according to your needs.

Comment: I tried to use uni_links previously, but now after reading the blog post you sent me, It works fine. Thanks Mate.

Comment: Good. If it works, kindly accept this as answer